# Regex: grep('pattern') catches 'pattern2'

Tags: regex

I'm looking for logical solution, using `regex`, so that I can query `grep` for `pattern` and not catch `pattern2`. Some kind of 'stop', or 'up until' logic.

This question is about performing this type of query, not about naming conventions. I'm not looking for a workaround, just the `regexp` logic.

For the sake of argument, let's make the context 'up to date' ubuntu bash. But what I really want is something that only utilizes the `regexp` logic.

For a list as below

```
entry    
entry1    
entry2    
entry.qualifier    
entry.qualifier2
```

pseudo command: grep("entry")

Note, this will match all of entries because as there is no 'stop' logic. I'm sure the solution is actually quite simple, I just haven't used regex in a long time.

Something like 'not anything after the pattern'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` supports word boundary so a pure regex based answer would be:

```
grep '\bentry\b' file
```

However `grep` also supports `-w` flag (match words) so you can also use:

```
grep -w 'entry' file
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GNU grep, what can help here are the wound boundary anchor operators `\<` and `\>` that it supports. That is to say `\<entry\>`.

POSIX [doesn't specify](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) any `\b` or `\<` or `-w` command line option. What if you have to use `grep` that doesn't have them? The problem can be solved by testing each line of the file with pure regular expression which must match it completely.

Suppose we want to pick out lines which contain the identifier `entry` that isn't a substring of a longer identifier name. Suppose identifiers are strings of English letters, digits and underscores. We can use this:

```
grep -E '^(|.*[^A-Za-z_0-9])entry([^A-Za-z_0-9].*|)$'
```

Note that the entire pattern is anchored on both ends, so that it must completely match an entire line.  It matches any occurrence of `entry` which:

- is either not preceded by anything, or else is preceded by a non-identifier character, possibly with other characters in front of it; and
- is either not followed by anything, or else followed by a non-identifier character, possibly followed by other characters.

This approach is also useful if you have a specific idea of what constitutes a "word" which differs from the definition used by the GNU grep `\b` or `\<` operators.  Suppose the file format is such that `entry123` is in fact two different tokens `entry` and `123`, and thus has to match. However `entryabc` must **not** match. For this, the GNU grep pattern `\bentry\b` or `\<entry\>` won't help; it will not match `entry123`. However, the above trick can readily be adapted to work:

```
grep -E '^(|.*[^A-Za-z])entry([^A-Za-z].*|)$'
```

I.e. `entry` surrounded by nothing, or else characters that are not upper or lower case letters. So this is worth to "keep in your back pocket".

Comment: /bpattern/b is all that is nessecary.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer  They are all that is necessary **If you are using GNU Grep**.  My answer specifies `\<` and `\>`: also a GNU Grep feature which will achieve the same thing. `\b` means "start or end of a word" whereras `\<` is specifically the start.